# Strcit mode says not closed resource but it is

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks

For populating a recycler view the following method is called to get all `order`s:

```
public ArrayList<Order> getAll(){
    ArrayList<Order> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery("select * from " + OrderEntry.TABLE_NAME ,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Order item;
            item = cursorToItem(cursor);
            items.add(item);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    getDatabase().close();
    return items;
}
```

I am running my app in strict mode and testing and a real device (Honor 4c). If I comment out the lines having cursor in them (from the line before if to the line after if) the code doesn't give any errors. This is the error I get now:

```
01-15 09:47:10.667 15301-15309/com.example.myapp E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                              java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:830)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:811)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
                                                                  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:649)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:235)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:199)
                                                                  at com.example.myapp.Data.Storage.OrderDbHelper.getAll(OrderDbHelper.java:70)
                                                                  at com.example.myapp.Data.Order.getAll(Order.java:171)
                                                                  at com.example.myapp.ReceiptsActivity.onResume(ReceiptsActivity.java:57)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6446)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3163)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

I am closing the cursor, what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `getDatabase().close();` ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, I was just improvising. The error has nothing to do with that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close the database object returned by `getReadableDatabase()`. Either `getDatabase()` acts on a different object, or some other function re-used it and forgot to close it.

Comment: that was correct, the Database class is a different class which I implemented. by calling `getDatabase().getReadableDatabase().close()` the issue was gone. thanks